# Multithreaded sender

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am working on sending traffic (such as UDP/TCP packets) from one machine to another. I am writing a C application which has 1 thread for each traffic type. I want these two threads to concurrently send packets.

Do I need to use any synchronization primitives such as a mutex lock within the sendMsg function since it is being called from each thread?

```
sockaddr_in dest;

 void * udp(void * arg){
     struct * info = arg;
     int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
     //set up socket info
     while(1){
         sendMsg(udpInfo, fd);
     }
  }

 void * tcp(void * arg){
     struct * info = arg;
     int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     // set up socket info
     while(1){
         sendMsg(tcpInfo, fd);
     }
}

     void sendMsg(struct * info, int fd){
         sendTo(fd, "hello", strlen("hello") + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof(dest));

     }
```

Comment: It doesn’t depend on any data shared (assuming dest won’t change) and doesn’t modify any data so it won’t need any synchronization.

Comment: Not for UDP, but if you don't sequentialize your TCP sends you can end up with mixed data at the other end. NB `sendto()` with TCP ignores the destination arguments, and may cause EISCONN unless they are NULL and zero.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a little unclear about how mutex works. A mutex is not applied on a piece of code, but a piece of data used within the code. Here the function is called by both threads, but there is no shared data between the threads. So as @Sami Kuhmonen said in a comment above, you don't need to use mutexes here.

You might need a mutex in future if, say, in case there was a third thread that pushed data into a (say) queue which your thread would then access from the queue and send to the connected computer. Then you would need to synchronise the way these threads push and pop data into and from the queue.

Comment: So, the two threads will be able to send packets on their separate sockets concurrently without any issues correct? What happens if one thread enters sendMsg and the send() call is taking a while? Will the other thread be blocked until the first thread exits?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the manpage for sendmsg you might see the following sentence:

> If  the  message  is too long to pass atomically through the underlying protocol, the error EMSGSIZE is returned, and the message is not transmitted.

Atomically means that the package is always send in one blob with no other data being able to insert itself in the middle. So no matter how many threads use sendmsg the kernel will mix packets.